# Deleting AWS SQS messages using Java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

I'm exploring the AWS SQS service. When trying to delete message from queue using java sdk i'm facing some issue.

A queue is created in SQS and it has three messages. The queue is backed by AWS S3 storage for handling large size messages.

Here is the method used to receive the messages by polling multiple times.

**Receive SQS message :**

```
private static void receiveMessage(String queueUrl) {
        // Receive messages
        ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl).withMaxNumberOfMessages(10)
                .withWaitTimeSeconds(10).withVisibilityTimeout(100);
        List<Message> messages = sqsExtended.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
        System.out.println("Number of mesasges : First poll : " + messages.size());
        while (messages.size() > 0) {
            messages = pollForMessages(messages, receiveMessageRequest, queueUrl);
            System.out.println("Messages in next poll : " + messages.size());
        }
        if (messages.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("displaying last set of messages ");
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("\nMessage received:");
                System.out.println(" ID: " + messages.get(i).getMessageId());
                System.out.println(" Receipt handle: " + messages.get(i).getReceiptHandle());
                System.out.println("approx. num of messages : "
                        + messages.get(i).getAttributes().get("ApproximateNumberOfMessages"));
                System.out.println(" Message body (first sentence): " + messages.get(i).getBody().substring(0, 56));
                // deleteMessage(messages.get(i), queueUrl);
            }
            deleteMessage(messages, queueUrl);
        }
    }
```

**Method to poll for messages:**

```
private static List<Message> pollForMessages(List<Message> messages, ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest,
            String queueUrl) {
        // display the received messages
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\nMessage received:");
            System.out.println(" ID: " + messages.get(i).getMessageId());
            System.out.println(" Receipt handle: " + messages.get(i).getReceiptHandle());
            System.out.println(
                    "approx. num of messages : " + messages.get(i).getAttributes().get("ApproximateNumberOfMessages"));
            System.out.println(" Message body (first sentence): " + messages.get(i).getBody().substring(0, 56));
            // deleteMessage(messages.get(i), queueUrl);
        }
        deleteMessage(messages, queueUrl);
        messages = sqsExtended.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
        return messages;
    }
```

**Delete SQS message:**

```
private static void deleteMessage(List<Message> messages, String queueUrl) {
        // Delete the messages
        for (Message message : messages) {
            DeleteMessageRequest dmr = new DeleteMessageRequest();
            dmr.withQueueUrl(queueUrl).withReceiptHandle(message.getReceiptHandle());
            sqsExtended.deleteMessage(dmr);
            System.out.println("Deleted the message with Id : " + message.getMessageId());
        }

    }
```

When the call to `deleteMessage` method is made, the program encounters the below exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSExtendedClient.deleteMessage(Lcom/
```

**Log messages:**

```
Apr 21, 2017 5:32:56 PM com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.ExtendedClientConfiguration setLargePayloadSupportEnabled
INFO: Large-payload support enabled.
Number of mesasges : First poll : 1

Message received:
 ID: f4f00368-b308-4763-84cf-8e33e1931fed
 Receipt handle: AQEBwhLDOIMobJazre1KoSYoMlHajHD1A6j7gZClk1h4FYWAmFd0p6wIFU69rSuhhVdQef+qF6E6RQIQLWaLqS2r0/Kfw3rUrmppIkTcowsVRW36uJ3p4UqnNjZu0cxncNMw78kHfHRej0gwH0gvvMedZXvEimoXUYZq1+K3Gz35etKsUR9EPKuroYaHZ6Aghdu0Osb4cQu+iLxlBrANhFl63762V7EDEEjSeULyQm52wS/OQq7JiktRWFgyGkp/41tHlN3ARB0v2MM3wXaoZMBt8bAyGURXb+Nx+5e3UoSI5J8pQccSwFnk70N1lV7XUswBTk4549uJ0FPlEMoFef6cxeFi1nxEXkfwIJQ9e93wMJUGLnhsx7rNWhS9w6UCVv4yZoARBsMrQbg287LkACLLnw==
approx. num of messages : null
 Message body (first sentence): {
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "fc1b19bc-6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSExtendedClient.deleteMessage(Lcom/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/DeleteMessageRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/DeleteMessageResult;
    at org.nfjs.aws.sqs.SQSExtendedClient.deleteMessage(SQSExtendedClient.java:149)
    at org.nfjs.aws.sqs.SQSExtendedClient.pollForMessages(SQSExtendedClient.java:139)
    at org.nfjs.aws.sqs.SQSExtendedClient.receiveMessage(SQSExtendedClient.java:108)
    at org.nfjs.aws.sqs.SQSExtendedClient.main(SQSExtendedClient.java:63)
```

I couldn't exactly figure out the reason for the exception.
Am I missing any thing in the above code snippet using java sdk?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using the [Amazon SQS Extended Client Library for Java](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib) myself, so I can not really judge the details, but it looks like it has gotten out of sync with the AWS Java SDK.

See [Exeption on AmazonSQSExtendedClient.deleteMessage](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/issues/12) for a (so far unresolved) issue on this, as well as [SQS Extended Client Lib not compatible with Core SDK 1.11.xx](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/issues/14) for a more general one.

The latter points to the *eventually* helpful [support aws-sdk-java 1.11.8](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/pull/11) pull request, though that one is pretty outdated by now as well.

Comment: Thank you Henrik for suggestion. The issue seems to be with the jar being picked from maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

The SQS messages are getting deleted successfully when the library jars are picked from `https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib` (downloaded the source and compiled).

However when it is picked from maven repository as below
it is having issue as mentioned in the initially posted question.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have raised an issue in github (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/issues/18) stating the same.